# Non-portable flags in variable 'PKG_CXXFLAGS'

Tags: r, makefile, rcpp

I added some C++ code to one of my R packages using Rcpp to help with some intense calculations. The `sourceCpp` version worked great. However, the same function was many times slower after actually adding it to the package. After some sleuthing, it became apparent that this was a compiler optimization issue. Long story short, I am trying to add a `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` file to `/src` in the package directory to optimize the code when available.

I'd like to submit the updated package to CRAN, so I need to make it pass the appropriate checks. Currently, I'm getting the Warning: `Non-portable flags in variable 'PKG_CXXFLAGS'`.

I've made various attempts to correct the issue. e.g.,

```
   PKG_CXXFLAGS = -O3
```

```
   PKG_CXXFLAGS = -g -O -mtune=native
```

```
   PKG_CXXFLAGS = -mtune=native
```

```
   PKG_CXXFLAGS = -g
```

```
   PKG_CXXFLAGS = -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -frtti  -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 $(LTO)
```

(The last attempt was from here: https://accio.github.io/programming/2019/04/24/R-Makevars.html, which was supposed to fix the issue.)

I'm still getting the warning. My question is: **Is there a simple, platform agnostic approach for encouraging compiler optimization via the `Makevars` or `Makevars.win` files in `/src`?**

Since I've not seen any `Makevars` of this type, I'm guessing the answer is no. If there is an approach using an `autoconf`, I haven't seen an example that I understand.

Comment: It's a CRAN rule that we have to take as a given.  The general recommendation is to add this to _your personal `~/.R/Makevars` instead_.  I think turning it on/off via `autoconf` is not forbidden, but just ... fiddly.  (Was just emailing with a friend whose package from CRAN would not install on my box unless I added a compiler flag.  He was trying the `autoconf` dance, that is my most recent example of "it's difficult...")

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the response. I thought that might be the case.